# Работа цикла for в игре "Быки и коровы". Питон

Tags: python, for

Делаю игру **"Быки и коровы"**.
Если буква из `testword`  есть в `correctword` и стоит в том же месте, то `bulls += 1`
Если буква из `testword` есть в `correctword`, но не на своем месте, то `cows += 1`
Программа работает правильно во всех случаях, кроме одного: когда игрок предлагает слово, в котором есть повторяющиеся буквы. Пример:

```py
correctword = [м, о, н, а, х] # загаданное компьютером слово  
testword = [м, о, н, н, н] # тестовое слово, которое ввел игрок. программа сравнивает его с загаданным  

bulls = 0  
cows = 0  

for i in correctword: # для каждой буквы в correctword  
    if i in testword: # если одна из букв есть в testword  
         if testword.index(i) == correctword.index(i): # и если индексы букв совпадают, то:  
             bulls += 1 # увеличить счетчик bulls на 1  
         else:  
             cows += 1 # иначе увеличить счетчик cows на 1
```

В описанном случае программа считает: bulls  = 3, cows = 0, а должна: bulls = 3, cows = 2
Если поменять итерируемый список:

```
for i in testword:  
    if i in correctword:
```

то также именно эта ситуация считается неверно, но уже иначе: bulls =5, cows =0.

Думаю, дело в том, что list.index(i) возвращает положение ПЕРВОГО элемента со значением i, а надо не первого, а каждого.
Что делать?

Comment: вы забыли опубликовать свой пример.

Comment: @S. Nick поправил

Comment: По правилам нельзя использовать слова с повторяющимися буквами.

Comment: Есть разные версии правил. По крайней мере при игре человек-человек (на бумаге) вариант с повторяющимися буквами отрабатывается нормально

Answer (score 1):

Объяснение в комментариях к циклу.

```
correctword = 'монах' # загаданное компьютером слово  
testword    = 'моннн' # тестовое слово, которое ввел игрок

bulls = 0  
cows = 0  

for c1, c2 in zip(correctword, testword):
    if c1 == c2:             # символы совпали - бык
        bulls += 1
    elif c2 in correctword:  # символы не совпали,
                             # но второй символ есть в первом слове - корова
        cows += 1

print(bulls, cows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант решения, использующий словари и множества позиций для каждого символа.

```
correctword = ['м', 'о', 'н', 'а', 'х']  # загаданное компьютером слово
testword = ['м', 'о', 'н', 'н', 'н']  # тестовое слово, которое ввел игрок. программа сравнивает его с загаданным

bulls = 0
cows = 0

correctword_map = {}  # словарь {символ: множество позиций с этим символом} для корректного слова
testword_map = {}     # словарь {символ: множество позиций с этим символом} для проверяемого слова

length = len(correctword)  # длина слова
for c in set(correctword):  # для каждого уникального символа
    correctword_map[c] = set()  # инициализируем значение в словаре пустым множеством
    testword_map[c] = set()
    for i in range(length):  # пробегаем по каждой позиции в обоих словах и
        if correctword[i] == c:
            correctword_map[c].add(i)  # добавляем в множество позиции, в которых встречается этот символ
        if testword[i] == c:
            testword_map[c].add(i)

for c in set(correctword):  # для каждого уникального символа
    correctword_positions = correctword_map[c]  # берем множество позиций этого символа в корректном слове
    testword_positions = testword_map[c]        # берем множество позиций этого символа в проверяемом слове
    bulls += len(testword_positions.intersection(correctword_positions))  # быки - прибавляем размер пересечения этих множеств
    cows += len(testword_positions.difference(correctword_positions))     # коровы - прибавляем размер разности этих множеств

print(bulls)
print(cows)
```

В принципе, можно сделать проще.

Например, не пробегать дважды по `set(correctword)`, а делать всё за один проход. Да и словари набивать не обязательно, можно просто работать с множествами.

В общем, есть простор для творческой доработки.

Answer (score -1):

> python3

```py
def each(s: str, f):
    sL = len(s)
    i = 0
    while i < sL:
        val = s[i]
        f(val, i)
        i += 1


def foo(a: str, b: str):
    # aL = len(a)
    bL = len(b)
    bulls = 0
    cows = 0

    def q(v, i: int):
        nonlocal bulls, cows
        if i >= bL:
            return
        isOK = v == b[i]
        if isOK:
            bulls += 1
        else:
            cows += 1
        # print(b[i])
    each(a, q)
    return [bulls, cows]


bulls, cows = foo('монах', 'моннн')

print(bulls)
print(cows)
```

### o ,-

- VSCode + python3 https://stackoverflow.com/a/47196099/4794368

Comment: Спасибо) Не могли бы Вы еще каждую строчку кода подписать #комментарием? Рабочая игра это хорошо, но хочется понимать, что происходит